# blend for virtual studio User control size in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, blend

I created a glass button, which has two layer for normal and mouse press.

But when I change the size of button is limited the bold of button in WPF.

How can I fix this?

[image: User Control]

[image: User Control in WPF]

[image: Change the size of user control]

The follow code is UserControl

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="YLM_UI.UserGlassCheckBox"
    x:Name="UserControl" Height="205" Width="393.5">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                        <Grid Margin="18.333,42.667,30,-32.666">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="0*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="90*"/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="104*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="62*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.523,1.2" RadiusY="1.108" RadiusX="0.58">
                                                            <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                                                <TransformGroup>
                                                                    <ScaleTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5" ScaleY="1" ScaleX="1"/>
                                                                    <SkewTransform AngleY="0" AngleX="0" CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                                                                    <RotateTransform Angle="1.601" CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                                                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                                                </TransformGroup>
                                                            </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#001BDCF0" Offset="0.962"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#CCFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                                                        </RadialGradientBrush>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.StrokeThickness)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="22"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="userGlassCheckBox" RadiusY="3" RadiusX="3" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" Margin="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="3">
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="White"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF0A0A0A" Offset="0.552"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF5A5A5A" Offset="0.526"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF040404" Offset="0.78"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Grid.RowSpan="2" Height="15.24" Width="0"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22.334" Margin="-0.001,9.173,0,0" Opacity="0" RadiusY="3" RadiusX="3" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="121.832" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform/>
                                        <SkewTransform/>
                                        <RotateTransform/>
                                        <TranslateTransform/>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                            <TransformGroup>
                                                <ScaleTransform/>
                                                <SkewTransform/>
                                                <RotateTransform/>
                                                <TranslateTransform/>
                                            </TransformGroup>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="White"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" RenderTransformOrigin="0.502,0.547" Height="205" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="393.5">
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="205" Margin="0.667,0,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle1}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="392.833">
            <Button.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
                                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.501,1.016" RadiusY="0.795">
                                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF0FE9F3" Offset="0"/>
                                                                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1"/>
                                                                </RadialGradientBrush>
                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.StrokeThickness)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
                                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
                                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="usrGlassButton" RadiusY="3" RadiusX="3" Stroke="Black">
                                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="White"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF2A2A2A" Offset="0.5"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFB3B3B3" Offset="0.47"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                                    </Rectangle>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="105.333" Margin="1.333,98.667,-0.5,0" Opacity="0" RadiusY="3" RadiusX="3" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="392" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                            <TransformGroup>
                                                <ScaleTransform/>
                                                <SkewTransform/>
                                                <RotateTransform/>
                                                <TranslateTransform/>
                                            </TransformGroup>
                                        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="White"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                                    </Rectangle>
                                </Grid>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Button.Resources>
        </Button>
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

Comment: Can you paste your code here?  If the external link expires, then the question is rendered useless.

Comment: sorry I try to paste here, but show me "× It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: Thanks to @jstreet